# Microsoft Edge saving console logs

Tags: javascript, logging, web, console, microsoft-edge

I am running a web page on Microsoft Edge and I need to save the outputted console logs to a file. Is there a way to do this? This is not as straightforward as it is in Google Chrome or Firefox where you simple right click on the console and copy and save the console contents. Also, the console logs I have are very long and the initial logs are getting deleted, as the number of console logs increases. Is there a way to save the output of the console log contents in Microsoft Edge, maybe by using some JavaScript function or other tool? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If you try it, it doesn't work. Also, when there is a long list of logs, the initial logs get deleted and it does not show a full record of all the logs. @Teemu

Comment: If I try, it does work. A long list will be a problem in any console ...

Comment: Actually, I don't get that problem in Google Chrome and Firefox, so I guess it doesn't happen. Well if it is a problem in any console, what would be a workaround for it then? @Teemu

Comment: Hmm ... it looks like Mozilla has fixed the issue lately. Not so long time ago FF console stopped logging after somewhat 1500 lines ...

Comment: Yes, could be. Seems like it is not fixed on Edge though. @Teemu

Comment: I am just selecting preserve log and scrolling down with mouse and copy paste. Its tough to do but no other way as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you select a log entry and then right click on the log message you can choose   `Save as...` and then save the log to a file.  This will save the log without any of the properties expanded.
[image]